# A question regarding the indefinite pronoun "something"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

I'm having trouble with the following sentences. Which one is correct, or both are possibly correct too?

> 1) Wow...something smells good! Is it hot dogs?
>   2) Wow...something smells good! Are they hot dogs?

I understand that 'something'(also referring to the plural object; i.e. hot dogs) is a singular indefinite pronoun.

Should I use *is* or *are* in this sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the word `something` is in an entirely different sentence from `hot dogs` so `something` would not affect the subject-verb-agreement in the next sentence.

In the first sentence, "Something smells good," the subject and verb agree.  "Something" is always a singular pronoun.

Take a look at this example:

> That hot dog **smells** good! (singular - correct)
>
> Something **smells** good! (singular - correct)

vs.

> Those hot dogs **smell** good!  (plural - correct)
>
> Something **smell** good! (**X** - *incorrect*)

The singular subject `something` and verb `smell` do not agree, even though `something` may not actually refer to a singular object.